# Storing NodeMCU data into MySQL database

Tags: c++, http, nodemcu

I am working on a project that requires me to store DHT11 humidity and temperature data into a local MySQL database. I have installed the XAMPP server on my computer and started MySQL server. I have written a .php script in htdocs folder that can insert data into the database. The .php script (dht.php) is as below:

```
<?php
class dht11{
 public $link='';
 function __construct($temperature, $humidity){
  $this->connect();
  $this->storeInDB($temperature, $humidity);
 }

 function connect(){
  $this->link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
  mysqli_select_db($this->link,'temphumid') or die('Cannot select the DB');
 }

 function storeInDB($temperature, $humidity){
  $query = "insert into dht11 set humidity='".$humidity."', temperature='".$temperature."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
 }

}
if($_GET['temperature'] != '' and  $_GET['humidity'] != ''){
 $dht11=new dht11($_GET['temperature'],$_GET['humidity']);
}


?>
```

I know that this script is working fine because the following command inserts the appropriate values in the Database:

```
http://localhost/testcode/dht.php?temperature=34&humidity=75
```

However, I cannot insert data from the nodeMCU into the MySQL database. My code is as below:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define dht_dpin 0
DHT dht(dht_dpin, DHTTYPE);

// Connecting to  WiFi
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include<ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "XXXX";
const char* password = "XXXXX";
const char* serverName = "http://192.168.X.X/testcode/dht.php";

void setup() {
  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
  delay(700);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
  // but actually the LED is on; this is because
  // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
//  delay(1000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)


  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print("%   ");
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.println("C   ");
  delay(1000);

  //MYSQL CODE HERE
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.println("Making request HTTP");
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin(serverName);
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    int responseCode = http.POST("/testcode/dht.php/temperature=33&humidity=77");
    Serial.println(responseCode);
  }
}
```

I do not see any data in the database when this command executes. Can someone point out whats wrong?

I've tried looking online and although some people have encountered similar problems, they haven't provided the .php file info, so I can'y figure out how to solve this problem.

I am following [this](https://github.com/Embedotronics/Sending-Temperature-and-Humidity-Data-to-MySQL-Server-PHPMYADMIN-using-Arduino/blob/master/DHT11_data_to_phpmyadmindatabase.ino) tutorial.

Comment: Well, your php file works, so the problem is with your c++ code.

Comment: Btw, you have to make a http get request, not a post.